# Distribution of dot-product of independent zero mean multivariate complex Gaussian vectors

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Let $X\sim \mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma_X^2\mathbf{I}_L)$ and $Y\sim \mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma_Y^2\mathbf{I}_L)$ where $\mathbf{I}_L$ is the $L$-dimensionel indentity matrix, be two independent complex Gaussian random vectors. How can we prove that these two random variables :
the magnitude of the dot-product of complex Gaussian vectors, normalized to unit variance
$$\frac{\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{L}X_k Y_k^{*}\right|}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y\sqrt{L}}$$ and the magnitude of the sum of squared complex Gaussian random variables, normalized to unit variance 
$$\frac{\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2L}Y_k^{2}\right|}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y\sqrt{2L}}$$
have the same pdf ?